# How to change the initial Route using SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

When the user logs in, the following code is executed.

```dart
login() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('loggedIn', true);
  }
```

And I want to control in initialRoute if loggedIn is equal to true, the login page will not be displayed.
How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use statics getter and setter on SharedPreferences:

```
class Preferences extends ChangeNotifier {
  static late SharedPreferences _prefs;

  static Future init() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  static bool get isLoggedIn {
    return _prefs.getBool('loggedIn') ?? _isLoggedIn;
  }

  static set isLoggedIn(bool loggedIn) {
    _isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
    _prefs.setBool('loggedIn', _isLoggedIn);
  }
}
```

In `main.dart` something like:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Preferences.init();
  runApp(const AppState());
}
```

And then just add a conditional to the route:

```
MaterialApp(
initialRoute: Preferences.isLoggedIn? 'main': 'login',
...);
```

Also, if you're going to use routes like that I would suggest to use a separate class, like `AppRoutes` where you can hold all routes and logic related to them and don't need to lose the `main.dart` readability.

Comment: i give this error :        LateInitializationError: Field '_prefs@366146318' has not been initialized.

Comment: You need to call `Preferences.init()` in you main.dart file.

Comment: @MahdiMsb look at my update.